# Is $O(2^{o(n)}) = O(2^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, exponential-function, computational-complexity

during an NP hard problem's theoretical complexity analysis, I am stuck at this term.

> $O(2^{o(n)})$

In particular:

> $O(2^{n-o(n)})+O(2^{o(n)})$

I end up at an answer $O(2^n)$ equating $O(2^{o(n)}) = O(2^n)$ by considering the worst case for the $o(n)$ as $n$.

Any push forward with a proof would be very helpful.

Edit: Changed the power term from Big-O to Little-ο. Thanks @Kenta S for the comment.

Comment: $2n$ is also $O(n)$, but $2^{2n}$ is not $O(2^n)$.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the term inside as little-o.

Comment: Then yes, this is true, since $2^{o(n)}<2^n$ for $n$ big. To be exact, if $\phi(n)=o(n)$ then for $n\gg0$, we have $2^{\phi(n)}<2^n$.

Comment: I think the answer is $o(2^n)$, you can't consider the worst case for $o(n)$ as $n$, as it is not in that set.